# Babel 7: Uncaught ReferenceError after transpiling a module

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, babeljs, chrome-promise

My Chrome extension project uses the Chrome-Promise module from https://github.com/tfoxy/chrome-promise/blob/master/chrome-promise.js in order to promisify Chrome API's callback-style functions.

Transpiling the project with Babel 6 has always worked fine. Recently I moved to Babel 7. Since then, when I allow the chrome-promise.js file to be transpiled by Babel, this results in a "**Uncaught ReferenceError: ChromePromise is not defined**" error when running the extension. The program works well when I leave  chrome-promise.js as is, untranspiled.

Here is an excerpt of my webpack config js file:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    cs: ['./build/cs.js'],
    bg: ['./build/bg.js'],
    popup: ['./build/popup.js'],
    chromepromise: ['./build/chromepromise.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{ 
      test: /\.js$/, 
      exclude: [/node_modules/],
      loader: "babel-loader" 
    }]
  },
```

and one of my package.json with the Babel settings:

```
{
  "name": "Test_CRX",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "cs.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node build",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
    "archiver": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-regenerator-runtime": "^6.5.0",
    "chrome-promise": "^3.0.1",
    "terser": "^3.10.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-umd": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "chrome": 60
          }
        }
      ],
      "@babel/react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
    ]
  }
}
```

Note: although I use Terser to minify the JS code, the error still occurs when I deactivate it.

**EDIT**
Check out the minimal repo I made at github.com/Steve06/chrome-promise-babel-7-issue-repo

Comment: How do you include `ChromePromise` in your project? through `import` or `script`?

Comment: Through the extension's manifest.json's background -> scrips key, like this:  "background":{ "scripts":["chrome-promise.js","bg.js"] }

Comment: Is the file's name correct?

Comment: Yes, I am aware I posted chrome promise without a dash in the original post, but the actual file name and reference to it in the manifest.json have always been consistent. I now even made a minimal repo illustrating the problem since I also posed this question on Github to the Babel makers. Check it out: https://github.com/Steve06/chrome-promise-babel-7-issue-repo

Answer (score 1):

`@babel/env` preset transpiles your files to `commonjs` by default, which requires the transpiled files to be included by `require` or `import`. To make this compatible with your Chrome extension, you need to transpile the files as `umd` module. Put this in your `package.json`:

```
"presets": [
  [
    "@babel/env",
    {
      "targets": {
        "chrome": 60,
        "modules": "umd"
      }
    }
  ]
],
```

You should also know that `source/chrome-promise.js` is already a `umd` module, so it actually does not need to be transpiled.

Comment: your initial solution was wrong in that the "modules" option needs to be outside of the "targets" bracket. Webpack threw an error in this respect. I edited your post. However, the final result is unchanged, I still get the uncaught reference error. And whether it is already a UMD module or not, the question asks how to get Babel 7 to process it without returning erroneous code.

Comment: I have updated the repo to reflect your suggested change